# Replicate email-to-case behaviour using threading?

Tags: email2case

We currently have Email-to-Case setup in our org. But we have a custom component that we're using to reply to the emails. Unfortunately, every reply to the email sent from the custom component is creating a new case and not appending the email to the existing case. Is there anyway to insert the token in the email header so that Salesforce is able to identify the email as a reply and not create a new case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `emailMessage.setWhatId(caseId)` solved the issue.

Comment: exactly --- emails will thread if they are associated to a Case